# CELL("filename") stops to work when excel file is saved at another location

Tags: excel

In an excel file I use CELL("filename") in order to get the path and filename of my excel file.

When I save the file at another location this formula doesn't work. Instead of displaying the path and filename it's written "missing".

When saving the file at another location I expect it to work. When entering the same formula agin it is updated. Since this is a template that shall be saved at different location it must work without doing this manually. Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Is your filename relative or absolute?

Comment: Are you using an absolute path to refer to the file name? Like `/files/excel/xyz.xls`

Comment: I tried it, and if I save it under another name it does not update it until I either refresh the cells (F9) or reopen the file.

Comment: @Mureinik: The file is stored on SharePoint and the filename is absolute.

Comment: Actually what I really need is the filename. I have logic for removing the path in my Excel file. Maybe that gives more possible solutions to my problem.